# Boolean logic for validation is failing

Tags: java, validation

```
public static boolean isValidReferenceCode(String rc) {
    boolean validCode = true;
    if (rc.length() != 6 ) {
        validCode = false;
    } else if ( !Character.isLetter(rc.charAt(0)) || 
                !Character.isLetter(rc.charAt(1)) || 
                !Character.isDigit(rc.charAt(2)) || 
                !Character.isDigit(rc.charAt(3)) || 
                !Character.isDigit(rc.charAt(4)) || 
                !Character.isLetter(rc.charAt(5))) {
        validCode = false;
    } else if ( (!rc.substring(5).matches("B")) || (!rc.substring(5).matches("N")) ) {
        validCode = false;
    }
    return validCode;
}
```

This is my validation method inside a big program, I need a validation that requires the user to input at least 6 characters, first two being letters, next three being digits, and the last character either a "B" or "N" right now it's not doing that. After some trial and error, the first two IF statements seem to be correct and work when I delete the 3rd if statement about substrings, am I using the correct Syntax here? Would really appreciate help!

Comment: `(!rc.substring(5).matches("B")) || (!rc.substring(5).matches("N"))` can never be false. Also, you might want to read up on what [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) does.

Comment: Thank you shmosel I really appreciate it I just figured it out when you said it can never be false, and I'm now using contains instead of matches which seems to be working, I'm new to java so I'm hoping to learn the correct ways

Answer (score 1):

Find below logic , it will work . Better to use regular expressions .

```
public static boolean isValidReferenceCode(String rc) {
    boolean validCode = true;
    String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[BN]}$";
    if (rc.length() != 6) {
        validCode = false;
    }
    validCode = rc.matches(pattern);
    return validCode;
}
```

Comment: You can further reduce it to `return rc.matches("[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{3}[BN]");`. The only catch is that OP's code handles other languages/locales, but I doubt that was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it is to use the original code with:

```java
} else if ( (rc.charAt(5) != 'B') && (rc.charAt(5) != 'N') ) {
```

You need both to be misses (i.e., use an `&&` instead of an `||`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a cascade of `if`s and negative logic, you can do the entire test more clearly in a single positive-logic expression:

```
public static boolean isValidReferenceCode(String rc) {
    return 
       rc.length() == 6 &&
       Character.isLetter(rc.charAt(0)) &&
       Character.isLetter(rc.charAt(1)) && 
       Character.isDigit(rc.charAt(2)) && 
       Character.isDigit(rc.charAt(3)) && 
       Character.isDigit(rc.charAt(4)) && 
       (rc.charAt(5) == 'B' || rc.charAt(5) == 'N');
```